# javascriptmvc root-level url -> problems

Tags: javascriptmvc

I'm exploring JMVC for the first time. I have my cookbook app set up and it seems to be working if I go to http://localhost/jmvc/cookbook. (I renamed cookbook.html to index.html.) However, if I make a domain pointer so that I can just go to http://dev.cookbook/ I see the main page, but the steal scripts don't load. I guess that makes sense, since they're looking for '../steal/{stuff}', and that path is invalid with that set-up. So what's the workaround? Surely I don't have to have a container folder for all of my JMVC projects.

Answer (score 0):

got an answer on the jmvc forums: http://forum.javascriptmvc.com/topic/root-level-url-problems#32525000000404011

basically, you build a structure like:

```
webroot (jmvc)/
   index.html
   myapp/
   steal/
   jquery/
   {other parts of jmvc}
```

in index.html, you have a line like:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='steal/steal.js?myapp,development'></script>
```